# How to load external source maps in Chrome 75

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, source-maps

I've looked around and there are similar questions but no answers that I could see.

I have a JS file - `all.js` and `all.js.map` (`all.js` links to it via `sourceMappingURL`). I've tried both loading up index.html as a `file://` and also over `https://`.

If I look at the source file in `devtools -> Sources` it says "Source Map detected":

[image: Source Map detected]

If I click "more" it gives this cryptic advice "Associated files should be added to the file tree":

[image: Associated files should be added to the file tree]

But no indication how to do this. Why doesn't Chrome just try and request the sourcemap at the `sourceMappingURL` URL :/, and does anyone know how I can add these to the file tree? Thanks.